# Disguise Multi-Page site as Single Page

Tags: menus, navigation, homepage, audio

I'm building a site that needs the audio element on the page to be persistent and keep playing when the user clicks on any navigation item. It's located in the header so I want that to be sticky too.

One of the solutions I want to implement is converting my multi page site to a single page so that if the user clicks on any navigation item on the surface it looks they're on a new page (url at the top changes too) but they actually aren't.

Is this possible? Is there something easier I can do to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you considered asking how to make your audio persist across pages instead? You've fallen into the X Y problem trap of asking how to implement a solution rather than how to fix your problem. If you had asked about making the audio play across the site then you could have asked in a non-WordPress context and gotten more people more views, and more possible solutions. Instead the question you asked is going to be much more complicated than the problem you have to solve

Comment: I'll make a second post focused on that. I need it in a WordPress context. I've implemented that solution before (pretty simply) just using HTML & JavaScript so didn't realise it would be complicated in WordPress.

Comment: it's more that the solution to making it persistent is probably unrelated to WordPress, e.g. saving the playback time in localstorage then resuming the audio if a playback time is saved, there's probably lots of solutions, none of which involve WordPress. You should consider asking on stackoverflow