# Make Audio Element Persistent Across Pages

Tags: pages, navigation, audio

I'm making a radio site and as part of that there's a listen live element which uses an audio plugin. When the user clicks on a navigation item to bring them to a new page the audio stops (understandably).

Is there a way to keep the audio playing smoothly?

Comment: which audio plugin? You didn't mention that in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392128/disguise-multi-page-site-as-single-page, have you contacted their support route?

Comment: Should have mentioned it sorry. Using the Shoutcast Icecast HTML5 Radio Player but it's really just for any audio widget in general. I've reached out to the theme designers who have their own in built audio widget without much luck.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I have a Radio station I built which I want to do the same thing. I use a popup window at the moment but the station now is able to use https so I want to unify the blog and station

Comment: I didn't unfortunately, just ended up having a dedicated page for it instead. If you end up finding a solution let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "normal" wordpress themes are not the right tool here, and what you need is a "headless" wordpress with {insert JS framework} to get the content via the json API and handle the page routing without performing actuall page refresh.

Another possible solution is to turn it from audio to video as browsers now have the capability to detach a video out of the browser window which means they should not be impacted by browser navigation

Comment: That is something I considered but the people I'm making it for were very keen on going the traditional WordPress route. One of the solutions I'm thinking of is to make it a single page with a sticky header and only the content below the header changes. (maybe by using sections?) But instead of the sections scrolling they should appear/disappear depending on the nav item clicked. Is that possible to implement?

Comment: For reference - [theme preview] (https://preview.themeforest.net/item/onair2-radio-station-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/19340714?_ga=2.201844563.356261119.1626688701-4884669.1626688623)

Comment: Amost everything is possible to implement, it is just a question of effort, and yes if you have a limited amount of content it is more viable. The other option is obviously play the audio only on a specific page with as many sections visual sections as you like and not to bother with the audio on other pages (althoug in theory you can transfer the position information to the new page but I assume the user experiance will be "jumpy" at page navigation/refresh.

Comment: Yeah it would be jumpy and it's also a live streaming link (it's a radio site) so I don't think that's viable. I've done something like it before already in plain HTML & Javascript using hidden divs. Just not even sure what to search to begin doing it in WordPress